# Suspend .Net Event Listener during Update

Tags: c#, winforms, events

I have a UserControl in which I've put a dropdown ComboBox and a DataGridView.

The ComboBox is a Filter containing items depending of the data in my DataGridView. The objects in the DataGridView have a property called ProductType. For every ProductType in the DataGridView, the ComboBox Filter adds it to the filter option.

The DataGridView needs to be refreshed when the following events occur:

- DataGridView_Load
- ComboBox_SelectedItemChanged
- RefreshButton_Clicked

The ComboBox is reinitialised when I refresh the data grid, since the list of ProductType present in the Grid might've change.

**The problem is that when I click the refresh button, the refresh function gets called multiple times.** Clicking the refresh button triggers RefreshButton_Clicked. The refresh reinitialise the ComboBox. Reinitialising the ComboBox triggers ComboBox_SelectedItemChanged since the selected Item is no longer the same. Then I have to put the item that was selected prior to the refresh, so another ComboBox_SelectedItemChanged is triggered. Etc.

Is there a way to suspend an event listener while I refresh and resume it afterwards ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could use a `bool _isRefreshing;` to indicate that you're currently in process.

The refresh button "hiding" its action seems like a code smell, to me. It's preferable for the subscriber to decide when it should or should not carry out its method.

```
if (!_isRefreshing)
```

The reality is that the event **is** happening, so disabling the listener obscures reality... What if there is some other listener which *doesn't* cause this update loop? You'd be affecting it as well.

So you want both worlds: the event fires properly **and** listeners decide they shouldn't act.

Comment: I guess you are right. If I were to add code to this event that should be executed even if the grid is refreshing, it would be problematic.

Answer (score 2):

You can temporaily remove the event by doing a "-=" operation.

For e.g if you registered an event like this

```
this.ComboBox1.SelectedIndexChanged += 
            new System.EventHandler(ComboBox1_SelectedIndexChanged);
```

you can temporarily unregister by

```
this.ComboBox1.SelectedIndexChanged -= ComboBox1_SelectedIndexChanged;
```

When you make the service/db call for updating/filtering the options. You can unregister the event and register them back after your data is fetched. I usually like to have the async event pattern for fetching backend data and I unregister my events(or in cases disable my UI buttons,forms etc) when I make the service call and enable/register them in the on completed call back.

Comment: Thanks ! Everything is a lot faster now.